# Analysing Contour Diagrams: Which function represents it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

So I'm trying to analyze the following contour map (visually) and point to the correct function that represents it. I'm not quite sure how to approach this at all, as everything I've tried gives me weird results without really seeing anything clear.

[image: countour]

[image: options]

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing I notice is that there are two pencils of parallel straight lines where the function is constant.  One of these pencils has slope about $\frac\pi2$.  I haven't gone any further with it, but I'd suggest you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The diagram is not symmetrical about the vertical axis, it can't be a contour plot of the two stated function involving $\cos(2x)$ which is an even function.
- If $y=-2x$, then we have $\sin(2x)+\sin(y) = \sin(2x)+\sin(-2x)=0$, which is a constant.
- If $y=-2x$, we have $\sin(2x)-\sin(y) = \sin(2x)-\sin(-2x) = 2\sin(2x)$ which is not a constant.

Hence the only possible candidate is $\sin(2x)+\sin(y)$.

Comment: It's correct, but how did you figure to try out $y=-2x$

Comment: I want to set it to a constant then I take advantage of the property that sine function is an odd function. If I want to set the second function to be $0$, I consider $y=2x$ instead.